# When i convert byte in string has a lot of unnecessary information c#

Tags: c#, encoding, byte

I need to convert this bytes in a string:

```
var smallDCWBytes = new byte[]
         {
              0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, 0xEF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x24, 0x16, 0x01, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x66, 0x37, 0x58, 0xCA,
              0xB8, 0x82, 0x00, 0x80, 0x53, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x44, 0x43, 0x57, 0x20, 0x52, 0x65,
              0x63, 0x65, 0x69, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64
         };

var localDCWResponseText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(smallDCWBytes).Trim();
```

this is the answered that i received:
"?\0\0???$\u0016\u0001\u0004\0\0f7X???\0?Small DCW Received"

I only need the "Small DCW Received",
how is the better way to do this?

Comment: An example of the string you want would help.

Comment: The presented sample bytes are strange (0xFE, 0x00 and 0xFF bytes) - are you sure this is really an ASCII string? The beginning looks a bit like an UTF BOM but it is not a BOM I know.

Comment: The problem is that the first part of the data is neither ASCII nor any other well-known encoding. And we don't know how to determine _where_ exactly your required string will start. You will need to add some context: do you know where this data comes from? Any chance _you_ know at which byte your desired string starts?

Comment: This is the problem, has a lot of command and a lot of kinds of bytes that i receive, I have to create a generic logic for all commands. The command that i received is in base 64, like this:
/gAA7//4JBYBBAAAZjdYyriCAIBTbWFsbCBEQ1cgUmVjZWl2ZWQ=

Comment: I changed for UTF32 and now the answer is "��Ё�������;"

Comment: Where are you getting these bytes from?  Your best bet is to just ask somebody what encoding they're using on this text that they're sending you, rather than trying to figure it out by trial and error.

Comment: _"has a lot of command and a lot of kinds of bytes that i receive"_ any chance to show maybe 3 examples of received bytes (just [**`edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42977681/edit) into your Question). Then it's easier to advise after spotting a pattern...

Comment: I fixed this. After I talk with the firmware guy, i undestand that these commands are divided into the header and the message Ansc. So, I resolved this problem using the 'Skip'.             var localDCWResponseText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(smallDCWBytes.Skip(20).ToArray()).Trim();

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is doing what is requested, because it is converting every byte of your array.
You can use:

```
var smallDCWBytes = new byte[]
     {
          0x53, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x44, 0x43, 0x57, 0x20, 0x52, 0x65,
          0x63, 0x65, 0x69, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64
     };
```

var localDCWResponseText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(smallDCWBytes);

Or, if you are forced to use that array, you case do something like:

```
var smallDCWBytes = new byte[]
     {
          0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, 0xEF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x24, 0x16, 0x01, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x66, 0x37, 0x58, 0xCA,
          0xB8, 0x82, 0x00, 0x80, 0x53, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x44, 0x43, 0x57, 0x20, 0x52, 0x65,
          0x63, 0x65, 0x69, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64
     };

var localDCWResponseText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(smallDCWBytes).Substring(21,18);
```

Comment: I need to use the array because i received a lot of kinds of commands. I tried to use your suggestion but is not working

Comment: You can try using you array and: var localDCWResponseText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(smallDCWBytes.Skip(21).Take(18).ToArray());